# republishing service in azure

Tags: wcf, service, azure, cloud, endpoint

I've published a service to azure cloud. I want to know if I add new endpoints and update service to make it RESTful, do I have to publish it again or it will be updated in the cloud automatically? generally, when a service has to be republished? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes when you are going to add a new endpoint to your Windows Azure Cloud service, your service configuration and service definition will change to include this modification. Based on this change you will repackage your application and deploy it using "Upgrade" method. When your updated package will be deployed, your instance will go down and then re-configured with newer endpoint settings to endpoint is available as it is configured.

If any changes which are limited to Service Configuration, it can be updated directly at portal by updating the Service Configuration.

Any time when you do code change or any of your application changes which modify the service definition you would need to repackage the application and re-deploy it. There are several caveats also but in general above does cover your question.